# Datastructure to efficiently access lines 'near' a point

Tags: data-structures, line, distance, point

Given a set of lines I want to filter lines based on their distances to different points. Since there can be potentially many lines, I don't want to calculate the distance between a given point and each line. I'd prefer to somehow filter out those lines that are far away anyway. I thought about using a quadtree which is good to prefilter nearby points to a given point. However it seems inconvinient to build a quadtree containing lines since every leaf in the tree has to contain all lines that cut the leaf's corresponding quad in the plane. Have some of you had a similar problem? Do you know common solutions for similar problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning

Comment: Usually you would put the line's bounding boxes into the quadtree so every line is stored only once in the quadtree. See for example my implementation [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes/blob/master/src/main/java/org/tinspin/index/qthypercube/QuadTreeRKD.java).